# Nested boxes packing

Tags: algorithms

I have many 3D boxes. All boxes are rectangular cuboids (they can rotate 90° so dimensions are interchangeable). The goal is to pack those boxes one into each other to minimize occupied space. There is no limit how deep boxes can be nested into each other. Single box can have multiple smaller boxes inside, and they can overlap.
I've searched for "bin packing problem" and "container loading problem" but both of them include just single layer of nesting. Do you know any algorithms/approaches/literature/academic papers or other keywords that could help me?

Comment: "and they can overlap" Can you elaborate on this?